# How to validate multiple fields with Django Admin Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two Django 2.2 models:

```
class Collection(Model):
    collection_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('title', max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField('description')
    document = models.ManyToManyField(Document, through='CollectionDocument', related_name='collections')
    page_rows = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    page_columns = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")  

class CollectionDocument(Model):
    collection_id = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    page = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # the page for this document
    page_row = models.IntegerField(default=1,)
    page_column = models.IntegerField(default=1,)
```

And I am using the Django Admin to add data to the models. The `CollectionDocument` is an inline in the `CollectionAdmin` page as shown below.
[image: Admin screen shot of the models]

The problem I am trying to solve is how to validate the data from this screen. I have validators that work to make sure that the `page_row` and `page_col` are not larger than the number of rows and columns defined in the collection.

The one validation that is troubling me is how to validate the three values - `page`, `page_row`, and `page_column` together? The validation logic for a collection is that none of the `page_rows` or `page_columns` are skipped for a given page and collection, and that there are no duplicates of `page_row` or `page_col` for a given collection and page.

For example,the Collection in the screenshot has a 2 rows and 2 cols grid for documents. That means for every page in the collection, there are `CollectionDocuments` in positions (row, col) (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2). So, the inlines would show for page, row, col:

```
document page   page_row   page_col
doc_1    1      1          1
doc_2    1      1          2
doc_3    1      2          1
doc_4    1      2          2
another entry like this
doc_x    1      2          1
is an error, as the page position (2,1) on page 1 is repeated.
Or, if the doc_3 entry is removed, then there is a missing document 
for page 1 at position (2,1)
```

A clean method at the `CollectionDocument` level does not have access to all the `page_row` and `page_col` information. A clean at the Collection form doesn't know about the`CollectionDocument`s.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to override the `add_view` and `change_view` of the `CollectionAdmin` class. This takes raw request and starts django's magic.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view